# Generate colors from diverging palette with arbitrary threshold

Tags: r, colors, color-palette

Say I have the following vector:

```r
vec <- c(-10, -8, -6, -5, -4, -2, -1, 0, 2, 4)
```

I generate some colors using `choose_palette`.

```r
library(colorspace)
palette <- choose_palette() # Select diverging colors.
```

Say that we select some diverging palette with blues/reds. What I would like
to do is to generate a vector of colors such that all negative numbers in `vec`
are associated with a blue color and all positive numbers with a red color.
Also, the larger is the number in absolute value, the darkest the color should
be, so to immediately reflect the distance to zero. The following does not work,
as the fifth number is considered as the threshold to separate blues and reds.

```r
colors <- palette(length(vec))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: So how many colors do you want? Do you want a unique color for every value? How are you going to use these colors? Are you drawing your points with `ggplot` or some other plotting tool?

Comment: I need as many colors as elements in `vec`. In this case ten, but I would prefer a general solution. I want to use the colors to color the nodes of an `rpart` object. The idea is to have the root in the "median" color. Then, predictions smaller than the root get blue shades and larger predictions get red shades. You can think of `vec` as storing the nodes predictions, sorted in increasing order, with zero being the rott prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Have look on:

```
your_ggplot2() + 
scale_colour_gradient2(
  low = "blue",
  mid = "white",
  high = "red",
  midpoint = 0,
  space = "Lab",
  na.value = "grey50",
  guide = "colourbar",
  aesthetics = "colour"
)
```

Low values will be colored in blue, with the minimum one = the bluest one ; and High values in red. The mid value will be white for the value 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I need to generate colours outside the ggplot environment. Can I use this somehow?